# jsviews - Update field of array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsviews

I have an issue with jsviews. I want to bind an array of elements. Each element is an object. Elements are added dynamicaly. Value of one field of each element computes base on another field. How is it posiible to do without refreshing array every time?

js:

```
model = {
    elements: []
};
$(function() {
    $.when($.templates('#tmpl').link('#container', model)
            .on('click', '#addElement', function () {
                $.observable(model.elements).insert({});
            })
    ).done(function() {
        $.observe(model, 'elements', function(e, eventArgs) {
            if (eventArgs.change === 'insert') {
                eventArgs.items.forEach(function(addedElement) {
                    $.observe(addedElement, 'value1', function(e) {
                        var element = e.target;
                        element.value2 = 'Value1 is ' + element.value1;
                        $.observable(element).setProperty('value2', element.value2);
                        $.observable(model).setProperty('recent', element.value1);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <input id="addElement" type="button" value="add new element"/>
    <div id="box">
        {^{for elements tmpl="#elementTmpl"/}}
    </div>
    <input type="text" data-link="recent" />
</script>

<script id="elementTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>
        <input name="input1" data-link="value1" />
        <input name="input2" data-link="value2" />
    </div>
</script>
```

I created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rjgh2sn/1/) that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ObserveAll()`: http://www.jsviews.com/#observeAll.

Every time the `element.value1` changes, you update the calculated properties `element.value2` and `model.recent`.

I updated your fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/1rjgh2sn/2/ with the following:

```
$.templates('#tmpl').link('#container', model)
    .on('click', '#addElement', function () {
        $.observable(model.elements).insert({});
    });
$.observable(model).observeAll(function(e, eventArgs) {
    if (eventArgs.change === "set" && eventArgs.path === "value1") {
        var element = e.target;
        $.observable(element).setProperty('value2', 'Value1 is ' + element.value1);
        $.observable(model).setProperty('recent', element.value1);
    }
});
```